# Laravel belongsToManyThrough double pivot relationship

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.5

Trying to achieve the following relationships:

```
Contracts have many Regions
Regions have many Contracts
```

So far so good, simple belongsToMany. Then:

```
Each Contract/Region combination can have many Jobs
```

So a Job can belong to a Contract for a certain Region.

I've got:

```
contract
 -id

regions
 -id

contracts_regions
 -id
 -contract_id
 -region_id

contracts_regions_jobs
 -contract_region_id
 -job_id

jobs
 -id
```

Which enables me, with a bit of joinery and a ContractRegion model, to preserve eager loading and do the likes of:

```
$contract->regions
$contract->regions->first()->jobs
$contract->jobs
```

etc. But it's messy, and actually adding a job for a contract in a region will be even messier.

Is there another way to efficiently achieve this triangle? Or is the best i can do to make a 3-way pivot between contract, region and job and resort to filterings in php and multiple queries?

Edit - Each job can also belong to one or more region/contract combinations

Comment: So a Job can belong to a Contract for a certain Region.you can use a hasmanythrough so job can be the table which can be that pivot..

Comment: you may be able to eliminate this table, `contracts_regions_jobs` but I don't know how much cleaner it would make it.  See you could add `job_id` directly to `contracts_regions` or change that to `contracts_regions_jobs` but you don't want one ID To be null, so if job is required that's what I would do.  Uniqueness falls by the wayside if one of the ID's can be null

Comment: Might want to look into polymorphic relations: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations. Make Contracts and Regions "jobbable".

Comment: use many to many polymorphic https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: Edited for clarity regarding jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your exact use case you could get rid of one of the tables

```
contract
 -id

regions
 -id

contracts_regions_jobs
 -job_id
 -contract_id
 -region_id

jobs
 -id
```

I would avoid putting null in for one of the ids, so this only really works if all three are always required. That said you could add a default job of something like none.

I don't know how much cleaner it would make it though.

Comment: Cheers for the response. This was my initial plan, i was trying to cater for a contract having a region without jobs, but it's apparent there's no stable way of achieving this.

Comment: Yea, having a null ID basically messes everything up, i cant remember exactly how, but I recall trying that one time..